# How to install php on windows xp

Tags: php, installation

every time I try to install php on windows I get a file called php-5.4.8.tar.bz2 I dont know how to install this kind of file can someone help me?

Comment: http://windows.php.net/download/#php-5.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the wrong file, you're on Windows not Unix!

This should help:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.php

yet, use a wamp server, it's simple and easy to use. enjoy your PHP trip ! :)

In case you're looking for a place to start learning PHP, I highly suggest this simple tutorial:

http://www.w3schools.com/php/

It's a very straight forward tutorial that'll get you started with PHP in no time!

Answer (score 7):

If you are new to PHP, then I would suggest you to use WAMP Server. Link below:

http://www.wampserver.com/en/

Install it, execute it, start working. Real fast and easy. It comes pre-configured with Apache, MySQL and PHP.

Comment: This was the easiest answer, the instructions on php.net are confusing and heck! X_x thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You have downloaded the installation package for Unix based systems. You want to download the [Windows Version](http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.windows.installer.msi.php). Note that you will also need to download an install [Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/download.cgi) with this.

You may find it easier to install a full development package. I recommend [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) or [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html). These contain all the tools you need to get started, including Apache, PHP, and MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

Compressed archive created by bzip2, a file compression program often found on Unix-based systems; incorporates the Burrows-Wheeler compression algorithm as well as Run-Length Encoding (RLE) for high levels of compression; often used for Linux software package distributions.

[Info about .bz2](http://www.fileinfo.com/extension/bz2)

You can unrar it using winrar